# How to change the field display of a nested serialized class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serializable

tell me how to display the "color" field of the "Room" class as a list of the values of the "colors" field of the "RoomColors" class in the "House" class inspector
I have already made the "size" field of the "Floor" class as a list, and displayed it in the inspector of the "House" class. Now I want to do the same but with the "color" field of the "Room" class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class House : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RoomColors roomColors;
    public List<string> sizeFloors = new List<string>();
    public List<Floor> floors = new List<Floor>();
}`
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
[Serializable]
public class Floor
{
    public int size;
    public List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
}
 
[Serializable]
public class Room {
    public int color;
    public int amountOfTables;
    public int amountOfChairs;
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;
 
[CustomEditor(typeof(House))]
public class HouseEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _sizeTablesProperty;
    private SerializedProperty _floorsProperty;
    private SerializedProperty _roomsProperty;
 
    private ReorderableList _sizeTablesList;
    private ReorderableList _floorsList;
    private ReorderableList _roomColorList;
 
    private House _house;
 
    private void OnEnable() {
        _house = (House)target;
 
        _sizeTablesProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(_house.sizeFloors));
        _floorsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(_house.floors));
 
        InitSizeFloorsList();
        InitFloorsList();
    }
 
    private void InitSizeFloorsList() {
        _sizeTablesList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, _sizeTablesProperty) {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = false,
 
            drawHeaderCallback = rect => EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, _sizeTablesProperty.displayName),
 
            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, focused, active) => {
                var element = _sizeTablesProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
 
                var avaibleSizeTable = _house.sizeFloors;
 
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(element)), element);
            },
 
            elementHeightCallback = index => {
                var element = _sizeTablesProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
                var avaibleSizeTable = _house.sizeFloors;
 
                var height = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(element);
 
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.stringValue) || avaibleSizeTable.Count(item => string.Equals(item, element.stringValue)) > 1) {
                    height += EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
                }
 
                return height;
            },
        };
    }
 
    private void InitFloorsList() {
        _floorsList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, _floorsProperty) {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,
 
            drawHeaderCallback = rect => EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, _floorsProperty.displayName),
 
            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, focused, active) => {
                var element = _floorsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
 
                var _sizeProperty = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(Floor.size));
                _roomsProperty = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(Floor.rooms));
 
                var popUpHeight = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(_floorsProperty);
 
                var availableSizeRoom = _house.sizeFloors.Select(item => new GUIContent(item)).ToArray();
                _sizeProperty.intValue = EditorGUI.Popup(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, popUpHeight), new GUIContent(_sizeProperty.displayName), _sizeProperty.intValue, availableSizeRoom);
                rect.y += popUpHeight;
 
                var _roomsFieldHeight = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(_roomsProperty);
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y + 10, rect.width,
                    _roomsFieldHeight), _roomsProperty);
 
                //InitFloorColorList(); I tried to display the field "color" of the class "Room" here, but in the inspector it was displayed as a field of the class "House"
            },
 
         
            elementHeightCallback = index => {
                var element = _floorsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
 
                var _sizeProperty = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(Floor.size));
                var _roomsProperty = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(Floor.rooms));
 
                return EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(_sizeProperty) + EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(_roomsProperty) + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
            },
        };
    }
 
    private void InitFloorColorList() {
        _roomColorList = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, _roomsProperty) {
            displayAdd = true,
            displayRemove = true,
            draggable = true,
 
            drawHeaderCallback = rect => EditorGUI.LabelField(rect, _roomsProperty.displayName),
 
            drawElementCallback = (rect, index, focused, active) => {
                var element = _roomsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
 
                var _colorProperty = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(Room.color));
                var _amountOfTablesProperty = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(Room.amountOfTables));
                var _amountOfChairsProperty = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(Room.amountOfChairs));
 
                var popUpHeight = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(_roomsProperty);
 
                var availableSizeRoom = _house.roomColors.colors.Select(item => new GUIContent(item)).ToArray();
                _colorProperty.intValue = EditorGUI.Popup(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, popUpHeight), new GUIContent(_colorProperty.displayName), _colorProperty.intValue, availableSizeRoom);
                rect.y += popUpHeight;
 
                var _roomsFieldHeight = EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(_colorProperty);
                EditorGUI.PropertyField(new Rect(rect.x, rect.y + 10, rect.width, _roomsFieldHeight), _colorProperty);
            },
 
 
            elementHeightCallback = index => {
                var element = _roomsProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);
 
                var _colorProperty = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(Room.color));
                var _amountOfTablesProperty = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(Room.amountOfTables));
                var _amountOfChairsProperty = element.FindPropertyRelative(nameof(Room.amountOfChairs));
 
                return EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(_colorProperty) +
                EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(_amountOfTablesProperty) +
                EditorGUI.GetPropertyHeight(_amountOfChairsProperty) + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
            },
        };
    }
 
    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        DrawScriptField();
 
        serializedObject.Update();
 
        _house.roomColors = (RoomColors)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Room Colors", _house.roomColors, typeof(RoomColors), true);
 
        _sizeTablesList.DoLayoutList();
        _floorsList.DoLayoutList();
        //_roomColorList.DoLayoutList();
 
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
 
    private void DrawScriptField() {
        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("House", MonoScript.FromMonoBehaviour((House)target), typeof(House), false);
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();
 
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class RoomColors : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> colors = new List<string>();
}
```

[image]
[image]

I tried to display the "color" field of the "Room" class in "_floorsList", but it was displayed as a field of the "House" class in the inspector

Answer (score 0):

Answer here, the display of fields for the Serializable class can be changed using the PropertyDrawer
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html